# PhpExcel xlsx to csv conversion issue on comma separated column value

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel, xlsx

I am trying to write a converter that converts the given Excel2007 to CSV format.
In my case, If a comma-separated column value comes in the sheet it needs to be write-in row  in CSV

Here is my EXCEL

[image]

In the above picture, the column profession has comma-separated values. When we convert this using PhpExcel it should be like following

[image]

Any Idea? Here is my code.

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


$inputFileName = 'SampleProduct.xlsx';

$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

foreach ($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
    $objWriter->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
    $objWriter->save("sample.csv");
}
```

Comment: Since that column has a bunch of commas in the data you may want to use something else, like tabs, as the column separator in the CSV.